# Custom Account Create Page - Filter Record Types

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have built a page that basically mimics the Account create page.

The page uses an extension to retrieve the Record Types for selection.

I have 2 questions...

1. How do I filter the Record Type picklist, to omit certain values?

For instance, Record Types on account 1,2,3,4
On the visualforce create page, i only want to be able to select 2,3 and also only render 2,3 on the table which shows the Record Types with description.

2. Also, I have created a list, variable, to render the available Record Types, to avoid doubling up (and meet the original requirement) how do i render the filtered Record Types (result of first question) on the visualforce page?

Thanks in advance!!

VF:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Account_New__tab" standardController="Account" extensions="NewAccountExtension" recordSetVar="Account">

<apex:sectionHeader subtitle="Select Account Record Type" title="New Account"   />
<apex:outputLabel >Select a record type for the new Account. To skip this page in the future, change your record type settings on your personal setup page.
</apex:outputLabel>

<br/><br/>  
<apex:messages />

<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock title="Select Record Type">

<apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel >Record Type of new record</apex:outputLabel>            
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedRecordType}" multiselect="false" size="1" required="true">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom" >
    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" onclick="encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Continue" action="{!redirectuser}"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>

</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>

<apex:outputLabel value="Available Account Record Types" style="font-weight:bold" />
<br/><br/>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
</tr>
<apex:repeat value="{!recordTypes}" var="recTyp" >
<tr style="border: 1px solid #e0e3e5;">
    <th>{!recTyp.Name}</th>
    <td>{!recTyp.Description}</td>
</tr>
</apex:repeat>
</tbody>
</table>

</apex:page>
```

APEX:

```
public class NewAccountExtension {

public list <RecordType> recordTypes {get;set;}
public string selectedRecordType {get;set;}

    public NewAccountExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

        recordTypes = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, IsActive FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='account' AND IsActive != FALSE ORDER by Name];
    }

    public List <SelectOption> getItems() {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Schema.SObjectType.Account; 
        Map <Id,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapById = d.getRecordTypeInfosById();

        List <SelectOption> options = new List <SelectOption>();
        //options.add(new SelectOption('--None--','--None--'));

        for(Id idx: rtMapById.keyset()){
            options.add(new SelectOption(idx,rtMapById.get(idx).Name));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public Pagereference redirectuser(){

        return new PageReference('/001/e?retURL=/001&RecordType='+selectedRecordType+'&ent=Account');
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to omit certain record types based on what? May be all you have to do is omit the results from your query to exclude record type names that you maintain in custom label or custom settings. You can then populate the select options list from the filtered list.

Comment: I like what you are saying! now, how to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from sfdcFanBoy, I managed to cobble together the Extension to filter the Record Types.

Note, this is not dynamic - If you wanted to add new Record Types, you'd have to edit the extension as well. Potentially calling a custom setting may be a way to do this.

APEX:

```
public class NewAccountExtension {

public list <RecordType> recordTypes {get;set;}
public string selectedRecordType {get;set;}

    public NewAccountExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

        recordTypes = [
            SELECT Id, Name, Description, IsActive 
            FROM RecordType 
            WHERE sObjectType='account' 
            AND IsActive != FALSE 
            AND NAME != ''
            AND Name IN ('rtype1','rtype2','rtype4')
            ORDER by Name];
    }

    public List <SelectOption> getItems() {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Schema.SObjectType.Account; 
        Map <Id,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapById = d.getRecordTypeInfosById();

        List <SelectOption> options = new List <SelectOption>();
        //options.add(new SelectOption('--None--','--None--'));

        recordTypes = [
            SELECT Id, Name, Description, IsActive 
            FROM RecordType 
            WHERE sObjectType='account' 
            AND IsActive != FALSE
            AND NAME != ''
            AND Name IN ('rtype1','rtype2','rtype4')
            ORDER by Name];

            if(recordTypes != null && recordTypes.size()>0){
                for(RecordType RT: recordTypes){
                    options.add(new SelectOption(RT.Id,RT.Name));
                }
            }
            return options;

        for(Id idx: rtMapById.keyset()){
            options.add(new SelectOption(idx,rtMapById.get(idx).Name));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public Pagereference redirectuser(){

        return new PageReference('/001/e?retURL=/001&RecordType='+selectedRecordType+'&ent=Account');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `getItems()` method, loop through your `recordTypes` List and add to the `options`.

```
    public List <SelectOption> getItems() {
        recordTypes = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, IsActive FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='account' AND IsActive != FALSE ORDER by Name];
        if(recordTypes!=null && recordTypes.size()>0){
          for(RecordType RT: recordTypes){
            options.add(new SelectOption(RT.Id,RT.Name));
          }
        }
        return options;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, please can you elaborate? I am unsure of the syntax etc.

Comment: Updated Answer.

Comment: Unfortunately adding this spits out "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"

Comment: the error is on page load or after clicking the button? eitherways, move the reportTypes query to getItems.  updated code

Comment: The visualforce table is now blank

Comment: i meant copy the query, not move! wrong word

Comment: Right, so the original list, lists all record types, the list you have supplied will list only the record types that are yet to be filtered? if this is so, why have the list twice?